# How can I configure Android to prevent the apparition of epilepsy-prone flashing displays?

Tags: screen, accessibility

From time to time, some program or website has epilepsy-prone flashing displays ([Example - do **NOT** click if you are prone to epilepsy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uivxk.gif)). Is there any to configure Android to prevent such displays so that individuals with epilepsy can avoid epileptic seizures when using their phone?

Comment: Control over such websites would come from the browser, so there is nothing Android can do there per se. Don't know about apps though.

Comment: @Firelord I was hoping they could prevent it at the OS level.

Comment: While I don't have epilepsy, this looks like a very interesting topic. However, a genuine question: do you know some ways to avoid it so that, while not perfect, we can perhaps find alternative solutions? I found some on [(Web) accessibility for seizures and physical reactions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/Seizure_disorders) to think if some apps can do it (like reduce screen's FPS to less than 3). But... even with Android being more than 10 years old, with millions of users & developers but no solution until now, I'm afraid it's not that easy...

Answer (score 2):

From what I just checked on a couple Android devices, the Android developers have provided multiple settings to help those with various health conditions, but I see none that will likely help those with epilepsy not suffer from consequences of the well-known flashing screen trigger.

It's definitely something that *could* be handled at the OS level, but from what I've seen, it has unfortunately not been prioritized by the Android developers or their for-profit corporate overlords.

BTW, [Gammy](https://github.com/Fushko/gammy) is an open-source project for Linux, FreeBSD, and Windows (*not* Android) that implements techniques that could potentially be modified to help those with epilepsy.  Converting it to a proof-of-concept that software can be written to help persons with epilepsy would not be too difficult.

Comment: Bummer, thanks for checking!

Comment: You're welcome Franck.  I added another section to the answer that might be of interest to you and others.